# how to remove an error in a Database sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table Customer_details_table has no column named "Card Number"

Tags: android, sqlite

String sqlQueryToCreateUndergraduateDetailsTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME_GPA + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                +"COLUMN_NAME" + " text not null, "                         +"COLUMN_SURNAME" + " text not null, "                  +"COLUMN_DATE_OF_BIRTH"+ "text not null,                            +"COLUMN_ADDRESS" +"text not null,"                         +"COLUMN_EMAIL" +"text not null,"                           +"COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER" +"text not null,"                            +"COLUMN_CITY" +"text not null,"                            +"COLUMN_PTYE_PAYMENT" +"text not null,"                            +"COLUMN_SHIPPING_TYPE" +"text not null,"                       +"COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER" + "text not null,"                            +"COLUMN_Password" +"text not null);";

I'm trying to save to a database but it giving me an error saying.....error code = 1, msg = table Customer_details_table has no column named "Card Number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in table or column names.

Change it to `Card_Number` or `CardNumber` and it should work.

**EDIT**

Looking at the error and what you said originally, I think you posted the wrong SQL.

You showed us your table creation SQL, but you say "I'm trying to save **to** a database"... And the error message seems to indicate that it was looking for a column, not trying to create one.

I think you need to look at your insert or update method SQL, where you probably typed it in manually instead of using the constant and accidentally put a space in there.

Comment: there is no spaces in my colunm name

Comment: Yes, there is, your error message says so.  `COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER` is **not** your column name, it's the variable holding your column name.  Somewhere you have `String COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER = "Card Number";`.  Change that to `String COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER = "CardNumber"` or `String COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER = "Card_Number"` and it will work.

Comment: I do not have a spaces in the code.......the erroro is ..........public static final String COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER = "CardNumber";

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then, the error you posted clearly shows a space.  `error code = 1, msg = table Customer_details_table has no column named "Card Number"`

Comment: I know even when is CardNumber it still showing me same error

Comment: Updated my answer, I think it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Also I don't think you wanted to put the constants into "", or don't you have them as constants?

It should look something like:

```
String sqlQueryToCreateUndergraduateDetailsTable = "create table if not exists  "
        + TABLE_CREDENTIALS + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " text not null);";
```

Comment: Well bugger, I completely missed THAT.  All caps means constants to me so I didn't even notice the extra quotes.  +1

Comment: yep, you are welcome :), btw, it helps to use code feature of stackoverflow... just press on these curly braces on top of your text window and then it'll mark your code nicely :)

Comment: Umm, I'm not the OP.. I posted the answer prior to yours. (And yes, I do know how to format code for SO).  :p

Comment: ah, hehe, sorry, didn't see that :P

Answer (score 0):

Your query is messed up. You need to give spaces between column names and their attributes.

for example, the following:

```
... +"COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER" + "text not null," + ...
```

should be like this:

```
... +"COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER " + "text not null," + ...
```

*Note the blank space after column's name*

Comment: It still giving me the same error .....error code = 1, msg = table Customer_details_table has no column named "Card Number"